# Mockito mocking a function call in an if statement

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to mock a function call to an external api that lives in an `if` statement.  I am not able to return the value I have in `.thenReturn`, and I am not sure why.  I have looked for answers to this on SO, but I can't seem to find anything that answers my question.  Thanks a bunch for your time!

Here is my class I am testing:

```
@Service
public class TwilioVerifyService {

    public String requestCode(String phoneNumber, String countryCode, String via) throws AuthyException
    {
        AuthyApiClient authyApiClient = new AuthyApiClient("<apiClient>");

        Params params = new Params();
        params.setAttribute("code_length", "6");
        Verification verification = authyApiClient
            .getPhoneVerification()
            .start(phoneNumber, countryCode, via, params);
        if (verification.isOk())
        {
            return "{ \"success\": \"Successfully sent verification code.\" }";
        }
        return "{ \"error\": \"Error sending code.\" }";
    }
}
```

And here is my test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TwilioVerifyServiceTests {

    @InjectMocks
    TwilioVerifyService twilioVerifyService;

    @Mock
    Verification verification;

    @Test
    public void requestCodeTest_success() throws AuthyException
    {
        String phoneNumber = "1111111111";
        String countryCode = "1";
        String via = "1";
        when(verification.isOk()).thenReturn(true);

        String result = twilioVerifyService.requestCode(phoneNumber, countryCode, via);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I believe I'm (or want to be) mocking out `verification.isOk()` to return true regardless of the inputs, but it seems to return false providing `"{ "error": "Error sending code." }"` instead of `"{ \"success\": \"Successfully sent verification code.\" }"`.

Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verification is generated from a call to methods in AuthyApiClient.

Ideally AuthyApiClient should not be instantiated in your service, but rather injected into it by the caller.

```
private AuthyApiClient authyApiClient;
@Autowired
public TwilioVerifyService(AuthyApiClient authyApiClient) {
  this.authyApiClient = authyApiClient;
}
```

Then you can mock authyApiClient and pass it in to the class being tested:
TwilioVerifyService twilioVerifyService = new TwilioVerifyService(mockAuthyApiClient);

That gives you more control over the class being tested and removes the dependency it currently has on the AuthyApiClient constructor.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  So is the issue that we are creating the instance of AuthyApiClient in the requestCode() function instead of passing it in?  Just so I can generalize this a bit.

Comment: Not the issue per se, but that is certainly in the way and making your life harder than it needs to be.